# SQL syntax error JOIN three tables

Tags: sql, ms-access, left-join

I'm trying to join three tables. But I get this error

```
Syntax error(missing operator) in query expression STUDENTAI.mėgstamiausia_laida = TV_LAIDOS.id
        LEFT JOIN MIESTAI
                ON STUDENTAI.kilme = MIESTAI.koda'.
```

Here is my code

```
 SELECT MIESTAI.pavadinimas, TV_LAIDOS.pavadinimas
       FROM STUDENTAI
                LEFT JOIN TV_LAIDOS
                        ON STUDENTAI.mėgstamiausia_laida = TV_LAIDOS.id
                LEFT JOIN MIESTAI
                        ON STUDENTAI.kilme = MIESTAI.kodas
        WHERE STUDENTAI.ugis > 190;
```

So what's wrong? Why I get this error?

Comment: What database are you using?  MySQL or MS Access?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query:

```
SELECT MIESTAI.pavadinimas, TV_LAIDOS.pavadinimas
FROM STUDENTAI LEFT JOIN
     TV_LAIDOS
     ON STUDENTAI.mėgstamiausia_laida = TV_LAIDOS.id LEFT JOIN
     MIESTAI
     ON STUDENTAI.kilme = MIESTAI.kodas
WHERE STUDENTAI.ugis > 190;
```

Looks structurally correct for any database . . . except MS Access.  In that system, you need parentheses around the joins:

```
SELECT MIESTAI.pavadinimas, TV_LAIDOS.pavadinimas
FROM (STUDENTAI LEFT JOIN
      TV_LAIDOS
      ON STUDENTAI.mėgstamiausia_laida = TV_LAIDOS.id
     ) LEFT JOIN
     MIESTAI
     ON STUDENTAI.kilme = MIESTAI.kodas
WHERE STUDENTAI.ugis > 190;
```

Note that this assumes that the tables and columns all exist and accented characters are allowed in column names and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is correct.  Either the table MIESTAI doesn't exist, or the field names STIDENTAI.kilme, or MIESTAI.kadas doesn't exist.

Do you really want to join kilme and kadas?

Answer (score 1):

This column name looks special:

```
STUDENTAI.mėgstamiausia_laida
```

It ran on my MySQL if I enclosed it in ``` `` ```, i.e.

```
SELECT MIESTAI.pavadinimas, TV_LAIDOS.pavadinimas
  FROM STUDENTAI
  LEFT JOIN TV_LAIDOS
    ON STUDENTAI.`mėgstamiausia_laida` = TV_LAIDOS.id
  LEFT JOIN MIESTAI
    ON STUDENTAI.kilme = MIESTAI.kodas
 WHERE STUDENTAI.ugis > 190;
```